# How can I avoid packing my Eclipse plugin in *.jar archive while building Update Site?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I cab export my plugin manually as a folder and I can set option to unpack *.jar after installation from Update Site. But how can I totally avoid using *.jar archives? Is there a way to build Update Site for my plugin with a folder with its contents except *jar archive?

Comment: Why don't you want a jar archive? That is the normal way of building plugins.

Comment: Because I have some scripts (bash scripts) in my plugin which should be executable in Linux by default. Jar archive doesn't keep execution bit so after each installation I have to make those scripts executable manually. It's not convenient. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ['features'](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseFeatureProject/article.html) to build your update site you can specify the 'unpack the plug-in archive after the installation' option in the feature.xml.

However I think this will still loose any execution bit set on files.

Update:

The 'build.properties' file in a feature can specify additional files to put in the root or other directories. You can specify the permissions for these files:

```
root=file:filename
root.permissions.755=filename
```

See the [Root file Properties](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm) help

Comment: Tried it. After packing in .jar execution bit is lost. Is there any way to avoid using .jar in Update Site? Like building Update Site with plugin folder, not archive. Is it possible?

Comment: Added details of root options you can specify in a feature build.properties

Comment: Solved this problem using your advice. I've set answer as accepted. Thanks again.